# Nginx with Ghost: 404

Tags: nginx, server, ghost-blog

I want to use nginx to just show my html page when at `/` and to show ghost when at `/blog/`. However it fails me with a `404`. But I can see the ghost image.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 123.456.789.123;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location /blog/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

The html page shows fine but /blog/ gives a 404. When I remove the `/` section and replace `/blog/` with `/` ghost runs fine.

When I remove the / section and set the

Comment: Have you configured the URL of your Ghost blog as, e.g.  `http://my-ghost-blog.com/blog/`? It looks like there is no blog at `http://127.0.0.1:2368/blog/`

Comment: It is set as `url: 'http://123.456.789.123/blog/',`

Comment: What does the `nginx` error log say about the 404?

Comment: Nothing. It is a 404 with a ghost image, so I'm guessing nginx thinks it's fine.

Comment: When you tested with `location /`, was the blog accessible as: `http://123.456.789.123/blog/` or as `http://123.456.789.123/`?

Comment: It was reachable as `/` Even when `config.js` root was set to `123..../blog`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102150/discussion-between-richard-smith-and-paul-woitaschek).

Comment: @PaulWoitaschek have you find a solution? The chat discussion has disappeared since.

Comment: @yvesamsellem The chat resulted in no solution. I resolved it by adding a server name,  server_name 123.456.789.123 -> www.abc.de